# Liferay Delete action redirecting to non available portal

Tags: java, liferay

I am working on DXP portal 7.2 and creating a CRUD application (Course) w Service Builder. When Delete task is performed on my data table, it works fine however the portal page is redirecting to a non available mode, example it says: Course is temporarily unavailable.
Please let me know what part I am doing wrong. thank you so much!
My view.jsp Delete part looks like this:

```
<%-- Delete action. --%>    
 <td>
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="deleteURL">
<liferay-portlet:param name="mvcRenderCommandName" value="<%=ConstantsCommands.DELETE_COURSE %>"/>
<liferay-portlet:param name="backURL" value="<%= currentURL %>"/>
<liferay-portlet:param name="courseId" value="<%= 
 String.valueOf(course.getCourseId()) %>"/>
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
        
<liferay-ui:icon-menu>                                      
<liferay-ui:icon url="${deleteURL }"  message="delete" >
                 
</liferay-ui:icon>
</liferay-ui:icon-menu>
</td>
</tr>
```

Below is my MVC Render command Snippet for my Delete:

```
public class CourseDeleteMVCRenderCommand implements MVCRenderCommand{
@Override
public String render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws PortletException {
        long courseId = ParamUtil.getLong(renderRequest, "courseId"); 
        
        try {
            // Call service to delete the course.
            _courseService.deleteCourse(courseId);
            // Set success message.
            SessionMessages.add(renderRequest, "courseDeleted");    
        }catch (PortalException pe) {
            // Set error messages from the service layer.
            SessionErrors.add(renderRequest, "serviceErrorDetails", pe);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Reference
    protected CourseService _courseService;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MVCRenderCommand and liferay-portlet:actionURL, using render url is possible but wrong.

The error comes from missing mvcPath paramenter in renderURL. Liferay does not know the destination jsp.

Some sample here

jsp: https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-commerce/blob/abf23f6175549f302f8b18ce5c0407c969a2e7bd/commerce-subscription-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/subscription_entry_action.jsp

action class: https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-commerce/blob/abf23f6175549f302f8b18ce5c0407c969a2e7bd/commerce-subscription-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/commerce/subscription/web/internal/portlet/action/EditCommerceSubscriptionContentMVCActionCommand.java

Comment: can you please point me to an example? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most important: "Thou shalt not change state in a render operation."

You're looking for an actionURL, and an MVCActionCommand to execute the operation (change state). Potentially a separate render, but that's often prior to the action (e.g. showing a particular option, with the possibility to delete it (if you don't have the delete button on your main UI)

Implementing a destructive operation within a UI rendering is just wrong and I'd recommend to go through any tutorial you find to learn the difference between action- and render-phase in a portlet. They're separated for a reason.
Typically, right after an actionCommand is executed, the UI is rendered.

On top, quite a critical part of a MVCRenderCommand as well as an MVCActionCommand is the `@Component` annotation (assuming you're taking the OSGi route)